# Angular 2 Pass variables to constructor in html

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am creating a component to be reused throughout my app, the important code below

.ts

```
export class DieInputComponent {
  constructor(private sides: Number, private dice: Number) { 
  }
}
```

.html

```
<input type="number" placeholder="{{dice}}d{{sides}}"/>
```

I am creating these objects in my html templates like so

```
<die-input></die-input>
```

How would I go about inputting the constructor variables in a html tag? For the life of me I can't find an appropriate reference on how to do it.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone pass ordinary variables to a component constructor. Usually, you pass services to it, like a preference service. When you get the handle of service, you can initialize this object.

Comment: For parameters to be passed to the constructor of components or services (which are instantiated by DI, you need to provide values with matching types or string keys and DI passes them for you. You can't pass constructor parameters to such classes directly yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need some value to be available inside your component class then simply use @Input variable and pass the value as attribute of your component

```
export class DieInputComponent{    
    @Input()sides:Number;
    @Input()dice:Number;
 }   
    <die-input [sides]='6' [dice]='1'></die-input>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the attribute values by using the `@Attribute` keyword in the constructor. This will give you the string value of the attribute you are searching for. For your example it would be:

```
export class DieInputComponent {
  constructor(@Attribute('placeholder') theInput: string) {
    // theInput.length > 0?
    // theInput.split into dice/sides and parse into integers
  }
}
```

You can read more about `@Attribute` here: [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Attribute-var.html)